# Hosting provider blocking IP addresses from "not so affluent" countries?

Tags: web-hosting, block

I have written few textbooks in English that are read worldwide and I use my website for supplementary material.

There is a reader from Sri Lanka who does not have access to this website. He also asked four other users from the same country and only one could access it. He concluded that my hosting provider blocks IP addresses from "not so affluent" countries. This not only restricts my readers, but is also clear discrimination.

I contacted my hosting provider, Asura Hosting, and they replied that they would not block access from their side, so it must be the ISP directly in Sri Lanka.  They also advised using Cloudflare to circumvent this.

The reader from Sri Lanka denies the possibility of blocking on the Sri Lankan side. He has never had a similar problem elsewhere. He also sent me this as proof of the firewall on the other side:

```
$ nmap mydomain.com
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-03-07 16:25 +0530
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.54 seconds
user@spectre:~
$ nmap -Pn mydomain.com
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-03-07 16:25 +0530
Nmap scan report for mydomain.com (198.251.89.144)
Host is up (0.0087s latency).
rDNS record for 198.251.89.144: s11.my-control-panel.com
Not shown: 999 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT STATE SERVICE
25/tcp open smtp
```

Above, I have replaced my website address with `mydomain.com`.

Could you please help me to find the cause of the problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: It could be a block from a local DNS provider in Sri Lanka.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran Is there any way that either I or the user in Sri Lanka can determine if this is a block by a local DNS?

Comment: There are many tests that can be run, the most simple is to ping the IP and the domain separately. They should both reply basically the same. Another thing is, maybe your user is behind a corporate firewall, or using a filtered internet. See if he can try from another location. Another thing to try is changing DNS providers, for example change to use 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: It is not given that the block is because they are from a poorer country - indeed that they can connect to your mail server is a little telling - it says its unlikely a routing issue.  Ido point out that the IP address 198.251.89.144 is listed in some blacklists - so it is possible that something is dropping communication because your site is hosted in a bad neighbourhood.

Comment: @davidgo They cannot connect to my mail server. I found this out by pure chance in a forum. Also, the person reporting the problem is a professional computer scientist and has a much greater knowledge of networks than I do.